# ¿Quién usa la palabra "corvo" para referir a un machete?

Tags: vocabulario, historia, lingüística, el-salvador

En un viaje al Departamento de Cuscatlán en El Salvador, oí a los campesinos usar solamente la palabra *corvo* para referirse a sus machetes, es decir, cuchillos grandes [como este](https://www.machetespecialists.com/product/imacasa-28-inch-pata-de-cuche-machete/):

[image]

La gente en Suchitoto (el lugar más urbano en el área que visité) parecía conocer la palabra, pero ellos me pidieron clarificar si yo había querido decir *machete* cuando preguntaba dónde comprar uno.

[Un poquito de investigación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corvo) revela que *corvo* se refiere usualmente a un tipo específico de arma histórica chilena. ¿Han oído ustedes la palabra *corvo* usada afuera de este contexto histórico chileno? ¿Dónde se usa el término *corvo*?

Comment: Yo siempre usé un corvo para abrir o partir un coco o para abrirme una brecha, y hasta para hacer algo de jardinería. Soy de El Salvador, y no creo que nadie allá no entienda la palabra corvo como un tipo de machete. No sé quienes eran esos de Suchitoto, pero el corvo es bien conocido en todo El Salvador. El corvo de Chile se parece más a un cuchillo o daga que a un machete. En El Salvador le decimos a este tipo de cuchillos que usan los asaltantes, "cola de gallo".

Comment: En México "corvo" se refiere a un objeto que tiene curvas, y no al machete.

Answer (score 11):

En El Salvador (en todo el país) se le conoce como  `corvo` a una especie de machete con curvatura en forma de media luna, a diferencia del machete tradicional, que no posee esta característica.

El **corvo** también se utiliza para cortar frutos, recoger vegetales, remover maleza, y en algunas ocasiones, para trocear algunos tipos de madera.

[image: Corvo]

Comment: Éste me parece ser un corvo más que el simple machete del OP.

Comment: De todas maneras, Centroamérica tiene la mejor selección de machetes de todo tipo y para cada uso. Yo trabajo en una ferretería, y el mejor catálogo de machetes que conozco es el de IMACASA. Me hace recordar el refrán: "si sólo tienes un martillo, todos los problemas parecen clavos." Por eso, ustedes deben de tener un vocabulario bastante definitivo.

Answer (score 7):

According to the RAE in its dictionary entry for [*corvo*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B3qNmyP|B3qrMlZ), this is a standard usage:

> 3. m. Machete curvo utilizado en la labranza y, por ext., cuchillo que se usa como arma.

Since it is not marked with a specific region of the Hispanophone world it is probably universal (although other people on this site will doubtless correct me if I am wrong).

Comment: La RAE no habla de una región específica pero les aseguro que en Colombia no se usa _corvo_.  Aquí un machete largo y delgado usualmente se le dice _peinilla_ , a los demás, machete

Comment: "Corvo" se usa también como adjetivo, usualmente para referirse a un sable curvado.

Answer (score 0):

The word "corvo" is a weapon used in Chile which some what looks similar to knife or [machete](https://thebestmachete.com/). You can even refer it as a [dagger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger#:%7E:text=A%20dagger%20is%20a%20knife,in%20ritual%20and%20ceremonial%20contexts.) as well, which is double edged and have a sharp curve on it's top. It was readily used in War of Pacific. It is mostly used for personal combat or to attack enemies. So, basically Spanish people and people of Chile use the word "corvo" to refer to a machete.

Comment: The machetes in the link you give do not look like double-sided daggers so I am not quite clear what your second sentence means.

Answer (score 0):

Soy de El Salvador y según recuerdo la palabra corvo es de Guatemala, al menos en mi zona la palabra mas usada es guarizama.